# Webstorm displaying similar files differently

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webstorm

What I mean is that webstorm colour codes everything based on if it is a function, object etc.
I'm using javascript by the way.

I have this line in 2 files:

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
```

file 1:
var is in orange, comment light blue, react purple and createClass purple

file2: same as above but React is light blue instead of purple

file 2 is working, file 1 is not. Does this mean it is thinking the React Create class is something different to what I think it should be? How do I get to be the same?

thanks

Comment: code coloring is based on parsing; purple is normally used for global vars and instance member vars, blue - for local vars. there must be something in your code that makes webStorm treat React in this or that way. What do you mean saying that file 1 is not working?

Answer (score 0):

The automatic formatting done by WebStorm is based on settings that can be different from user to user. Without having more code than that line or knowing your settings, it is impossible to say why it is showing differently in the two files or how to get them to be the same.

You can follow the instructions provided by Jet Brains on changing the colors and fonts settings to help determine what each color/font means.(https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html)

Identifying what each color means should help you to determine the difference between the two lines/files and how to adjust your code.

Good Luck!